# How to create card deck that can add item on bottom of the deck using Jetpack compose

Tags: android, algorithm, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm trying to create a card deck using jetpack compose. The card deck must be able to add items on the bottom of the deck dynamically and a user will only be able to draw a card from the top of the deck. When a user draws a card, a new card will be added to the bottom of the deck. I don't want to recompose a whole deck when I add a new card to the bottom of the deck. I'd like to do it without any UI changes on top of the deck. (A user can only see the card on the top of the deck) Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: please add some codes that you tried to help us understand your situation

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.